# Custom type and using Settings Designer for use with persisting user settings

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, configuration

I have created a custom config type using the custom configuration designer (http://csd.codeplex.com/).
This works fine when using as per normal by declaring in .
However if I wanted to store the custom type to store usersettings and use Settings Designer in Visual studio then after setting the Type, I can't seem to set a valid value.
I have looked around for the answer but wasn't able to find anything similar on google.
Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469474/custom-types-in-settings

Answer (score 0):

Custom configuration sections (for example - created by CSD) are not proposed for using in standard Visual Studio designer. You can only change config file in XML view by hand.

Comment: You have misunderstood my question, what I have is custom generated type and want to know if I can set the value for it using either the settings designer or the app.config inside the userSettings configuration element.